# Collapsible HTML table controled by button with multiple sub-tables with different datasets

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create collapsible table controled by button with multiple sub-tables.

Example:
Main table which will have three buttons and every buton will display subtable with different contect (one button will show subtable with dataset1, second button will show subtable with dataset2 etc...)
Datasets will be different (different headhers and data).
I am filling these data by php from mysql database
In case that subtable with dataset1 is shown and user click on button for dataset2 contect will be changed.

I am not very familiar with javascript and 2 hours of google search found nothing. This is all I have and I do not know how I can achieve what I need as I just started to use Javascript.

I will be very happy for any help or for posting any post which will help me to fulfill this requirement.

Many thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>XXX</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
      <th>XXX/s</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="expandable">
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="+">
      </td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>

    <tr>
      <th></td>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
    </tr>      
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="expandable">
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="+">
      </td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
      <td>DUMMY</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th></td>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
      <th>SUB-DUMMY</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
      <td>SUB-DUMMY</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

```
</script>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each(function() { 
      if (!($(this).is('.expandable')))
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('.expandable input[type=button]').click(function() { 
      var trElem = $(this).closest("tr");
      trElem.nextAll('tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.expandable')) {
          return false;
        }
        $(this).toggle();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Jquery and Ajax script with help of w3schools.